# How can I have a column auto generated on inserts and updates as a function of other columns?

Tags: sql-server

In a nutshell, here's what I'm trying to do:

```
create function Composite(@year int, @major int, @minor int)
returns int
    begin
        return(select(@year*10000 + @major*100 + @minor))
    end
go

create table AutoGeneratedColumn (
    [year] int,
    [major] int,
    [minor] int,
    [composite] int default Composite([year], [major], [minor])
)
```

(This doesn't work.)

I want the column `composite` to be a composite value of `year`, `major`, and `minor`, such that `composite` is always equal to `Composite(year, major, minor)`. Ideally, explicit values wouldn't be able to be supplied on inserts, and updates should update `composite` as well. I'm not sure how to do this, though.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a computed column:

```
create table AutoGeneratedColumn (
    [year] int,
    [major] int,
    [minor] int,
    [composite] as ([year]*10000 + [major]*100 + [minor])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called a computed column.  You don't need the function call.

```
create table AutoGeneratedColumn (
    [year] int,
    [major] int,
    [minor] int,
    [composite]  AS ([year] * 10000 + [major] * 100 + [minor]),
)
```

Comment: lol 4 seconds earlier than my almost identical response. :D Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a function for this. This is a basic computed column.

```
create table AutoGeneratedColumn (
    [year] int,
    [major] int,
    [minor] int,
    [composite] as ([year]*10000 + major*100 + minor)
)
```